# Swing plugin visual swing class

Tags: swing

I am trying to do  a demo Swing application. So Where can i find help or tutorial for 'visual swing class' eclipse plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start with the Java Swing Tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Or the NetBeans tutorial:

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/matisse.html

Comment: Sure.. I will start that, but to meet deadlines thought of using pluggins

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "using plugins"? NetBeans has a visual GUI builder that might help you getting started